AKS with Ingress controller ends connection after 60s
In my setup I have django app served with channels that use Azure Cache for Redis. Networking forks as follows: there is standard load balancer and nginx-ingress controller after that which routes traffic to my backend pods.
No matter how I configure Load balancer or ingress it keeps shutting down connections to redis after 60s.
I know that problem lies either on AKS or ingress-controller because if i run same setup outside AKS it does not timeout things. Issue does not appear if I connect backend to in-cluster redis instance. I'm certain that load balancer rules allow idle connection for at least 30 min. There is no firewall on at the moment. I eliminated in-app timeouts (ran it locally with no timeouts), and ingress timeouts (setting it to value lower than 60s causes it to timeout connection).
Here is my ingress configuration and ConfigMap I applied to ingress-controller.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ include "HELPERS.name" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "HELPERS.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "HELPERS.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 5m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-keepalive-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: '500'
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: {{ .Values.cert_issuer_prefix }}-cert-issuer
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "30m"


apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-test-ocean-ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.35.0
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-ingress-test-ocean
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  proxy-connect-timeout: "420"
  proxy-read-timeout: "420"
  proxy-send-timeout: "420"
  keepalive-timeout : "420"
  keep-alive: "420"
  upstream-keepalive-timeout: "420"

Do you guys have any idea which party might cause that issue, and how I can change Load balancer/AKS/ingress-controller/any other service config to make it stop timing out connections?

Can you please update your configmap data like this and give it a try- data:   proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"   proxy-read-timeout: "3600"   proxy-send-timeout: "3600"   keepalive-timeout: "3600"   upstream-keepalive-timeout: "3600"   worker-shutdown-timeout: "3600"   client-body-timeout: "3600"   client-header-timeout: "3600"   http2-max-field-size: "16k"   http2-max-header-size: "32k"   large-client-header-buffers: "4 32k"   server-tokens: "false"   ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"   use-http2: "true"

And also verify that your nginx ingress controller deployment references the ConfigMap correctly like this- spec:       containers:       - name: nginx-ingress-controller         image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:latest         args:           - /nginx-ingress-controller           - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration         env:           - name: POD_NAME             valueFrom:               fieldRef:                 fieldPath: metadata.name and the Load Balancer has idle timeout set to let's say 30 minutes.

Hi @Arko! Thanks for your comment. I did all above and confirmed in ingress log that new config map was applied, sadly nothing changed. It keeps throwing an errors such as
INFO 2024-06-19 08:59:56,846 daphne.server Timing out client: IPv4Address(type='TCP', host='10.244.5.45', port=58986)
if that helps I noted that only outbound traffic has this problem. Inbound long-living connections such as websockets works without any issues. Load Balancer idle timeout is set to 30 minutes

To give even more context I did more debugging and bypassed ingress-controller, so right now with setup: pod with backend -> load balancer service issue still persist.

since the issue persists even when bypassing Ingress, and only affects outbound traffic, the problem might be related to the network configuration at AKS level or the way the services are interacting with Azure Cache for Redis. Would recommend you check few more things like az network nsg list --resource-group yourRg or increase TCP Keepalive settings or use kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- tcpdump -i any -w /tmp/dump.pcap to capture and analyze the traffic between your application pods and Azure Cache for Redis.
